# typescript interface for object from _.mapKeys(items, 'id')

Tags: typescript

I'm using react, Redux, and trying to use typescript on the component.  in the reducer, I use lodash mapKeys to flatten the array of objects from:

```
 [  
   {id:1, blah blah}
   {id:2, blah blah}
 ]

to: 
 {
    "1", {id:1, blah blah},
    "2", {id:2, blah blah}
 }
```

this helps the reducer in that I don't play array games.

**the problem**: how can I define that flattened object in a typescript interface?

**more details**....

I have an interface of Itodo:

```
  export interface ITodo {
    id:number;
    subject:string;
    body:string;
    status: number;
    result:number;
  }
```

In my reducer, i change this using lodash mapKeys, so that instead of an array I get back a series of properties with the id as the property name. (see below)

how can I create an interface that will express this for my react component?

```
  const response =
   [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "subject": "subject a",
       "body": "body a",
       "status": 0,
       "result": 0,
       "delete": null
     },
     {
       "id": 2,
       "subject": "subject b",
       "body": "body b",
       "status": 2,
       "result": 2,
       "delete": null
     },
     {
       "id": 3,
       "subject": "subject c",
       "body": "body c",
       "status": 2,
       "result": 2,
       "delete": null
     }
   ]

   const mapped = _.mapKeys(response,'id')

   console.log (JSON.stringify(mapped,null,2)
   {
     "1": {
       "id": 1,
       "subject": "subject a",
       "body": "body a",
       "status": 0,
       "result": 0,
       "delete": null
     },
     "2": {
       "id": 2,
       "subject": "subject b",
       "body": "body b",
       "status": 2,
       "result": 2,
       "delete": null
     },
     "3": {
       "id": 3,
       "subject": "subject c",
       "body": "body c",
       "status": 2,
       "result": 2,
       "delete": null
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would do:

```
export interface ITodo {
    id:number;
    subject:string;
    body:string;
    status: number;
    result:number;
  }

interface ITodoObject {
    [key: number]: ITodo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Record<K,T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt):

```
export interface ITodo {
    id:number;
    subject:string;
    body:string;
    status: number;
    result:number;
}

export type ITodoMap = Record<number, ITodo>;

const todoList: ITodo[] = [
    { id: 1, subject: "", body: "", status: 0, result: 0 },
    { id: 2, subject: "", body: "", status: 0, result: 0 },
];

const todoMap: ITodoMap  = {
    1: { id: 1, subject: "", body: "", status: 0, result: 0 },
    2: { id: 2, subject: "", body: "", status: 0, result: 0 },
};
```

Comment: thank you, but I'm trying to describe in the interface

Comment: In this case, you may use a type. An interface would not describe it properly. I have updated the code snippet.